# Azure Mobile service database row count

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a free mobile service on Azure and there are 3 tables. Can I somehow get number of rows in each table (using Azure portal or code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to https://manage.windowsazure.com and open your database there

- click on the the little blue cloud to the left of the "Dashboard"
- at the bottom will be a section titled "Connect to your
  database"
- clock on the "Run Transact-SQL queries against your SQL database (this may prompt you to add your ip to the allowed ips in the firewall)
- Log in to your database

From there you can run queries against your database such as

```
select count(1) from [name of your table]
```

Comment: I wasn't able to find this tool in the new portal.  I hope that doesn't mean it's not there...

Comment: Old and new Azure portal contains a bit different functionality, therefore in reality you need to use both. I haven't checked, but it might be that this functionality is not ported to the new portal yet.

Comment: Thanks. There is an info that my tables use 13mb. So why azure portal says that my 20mb database is full?